# OR-PMSA-35 ERROR CODE, Does the Google IAB immediately work right after release?

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Today I released my application and I download the production version from play store, then I get the following error when I try to purchase in app subscription:

OR-PMSA-35

The native dialog ask me to try again or contact my bank.

When I tried in different application (I tried in "Calm") the purchase works fine.
I use flutter with Revenue Cat, but I think this bug related to play store/android.

Is there anybody here who experience same issue?

Answer (score -1):

Hello i have right now the same problem but i just want to buy stuff with google pay i'm not an app developper. I contacted the google assistance for google pay who told me that the problem was not on my side and the bank where I am told me that there was a problem with "securipass" (it's a kind of A2F to validate operation in my bank) so I correct the "problem" with securipass but I still have the problem:/ if you find solutions I'm interested.

I have a french bank and I have a Xiaomi 13 pro and a week ago there was no problem. The problem is the same when i tried to use paypal

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34256872)